# PGP - GnuPG - A few questions

Tags: pgp, encryption-asymmetric, gnupg, openpgp

I want to use GnuPG (http://www.gnupg.org/), the open source software that is a full replacement for PGP.

The software looks great though I have never used it before.

I will be using the software to encrypt files to transfer via the web, I am not using the software for emails.

I have a few questions:

1. What are recommended GUI's available for windows and Ubuntu?
2. I want to generate a generate a key pair that is Diffee Hellman (DH/DSS) not RSA. What is the line command to do this? As well using the key length of 2048.
3. Once I generate my public-private key pair, how do I sign someone elses public key that I have through command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of these are found in the manual.

1. http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/frontends.html
2. http://www.dewinter.com/gnupg_howto/english/GPGMiniHowto-3.html
3. http://www.dewinter.com/gnupg_howto/english/GPGMiniHowto-3.html#ss3.6